# Passing a string through an array looking for regEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I'm currently making a chatbox in JQuery. I've been using indexOf but I think it might be more efficient to use regExp.

my current code is

```
function ai(message){
if (username.length<3){
  username = message;
  send_message("Nice, to meet you " + username + ", how are you doing?");
}
 if(message.indexOf("how are you?")>=0) {
  send_message("I'm feeling great!");
}
 if(message.indexOf("weather")>=0 ){
  send_message("In England it is shitty");
}
var n = message.search(/\b(cat|cats|kitten|feline)\b/i);
 if (n !== -1) {
  send_message("i hate cats");

}
else {
          for (i=0; i <= botChat.length; i++) {
            var re = new RegExp (botChat[i][0], 'i');
                if (re.test(message)) {
                  var length = botChat[i].length - 1;
                  var  index = Math.ceil( length * Math.random());
                  var reply = (botChat[i][index]);
                  send_message(reply);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and a typical line from my array is

```
new Array ("I need (.*)\." , "Why do you need $1?", "Would it really help you to get $1?" , "Are you sure you need $1?"),
```

i'm trying to demonstrate the ways of creating a chatbot. The first four responses work perfectly
it takes a name, comments on the weather and can search for cats. What it can't do is perform the loop. Has anyone any suggestions?

Comment: your method definition for `conversationpatterns` may have a compilation issue. Can you share its code ?

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do with the values in the array?

Comment: in the example i'm hoping that if i were to write the phrase ' i need pie' it would send the message 'would it really help you to get pie?' or"Why do you need pie?' or   "Are you sure you need pie?"

Comment: nction conversationpatterns(message) {
       for (i=0; i < botChat.length; i++) {
        re = new RegExp (botChat[i][0], "i");
        if (re.test(message)) {
          length = botChat[i].length - 1;
          index = Math.ceil( length * Math.random());
          send_message(botChat[i][index]);

changed it so that it tests the message its given